# SQL Server - Write commands blocked by Full Text Population

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I'm trying to make some changes / updates to a certain large table in a SQL Server database. Every write command I try to make is blocked. I have determined that it is process 19 that is blocking the commands by running

```
select cmd,* from sys.sysprocesses
```

process 19 is FT CRAWL, which I'm assuming is the full-text population for the table, which seems to currently be populating.

All attempts to stop the full text population fail due to timeout, and seem to also have been blocked by spid 19.

Is there any way to kill the full text population? Thanks for the help, I need it!

Comment: I don't really know how to stop it (maybe try using the manager system looking for the tables that have full text index if they are not lots of them). However, I sometimes did have problems with the full text index and the first thing I've tried was reading the log which helped me. You should search it in the log directory "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG".  Sorry that I couldn't help you very much =(.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! The population ended up finishing overnight and it was fine in the morning; it's just a pain having to wait for something like that to finish with no way to abort.

Comment: @Gaspa79 Thanks! looking in the log revelaled that the db was full (10GB)